# Django: password_reset_form.html: Change directory in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

The Django instructions say if I want to modify the email going out for password resets, I have to put it in register/password_reset_email.html   err....What if I want to put it in account/password_reset_email.html instead?

Thanks

Comment: Try it, and see what happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`password_reset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) view takes an optional `email_template_name` argument that you can use to override the default template location.